# Rails gem for date dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

Is there a rails gem/plugin where one dropdown is each for day, month and year? I currently have it as a plain text fields and I think dropdowns would be better for this. Had anyone had similar need/experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date_select` gives you 3 select tags, one for year, month and day. You don't need a gem for it.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select